# IntelliJ Idea: Deploy a simple Java servlet (no JSP) to Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, intellij-idea

I tried following the tutorial [here](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_a_simple_Web_application_and_deploying_it_to_Tomcat) to deploy a servlet but that only works if you specify a JSP file. The problem is that without the JSP, I don't know what to set the **Startup Page** in the Tomcat Run/Debug configuration. So any idea what to do?

Thanks!

Comment: The link to the tutorial shows how to include a normal java class in a jsp, but not how to create a SERVLET with intelliJ. A servlet is a class that extends HttpServlet and has a doGet and/or doPost Method.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should define a `servlet-mapping` in the `web.xml` like this:

[image: URL pattern]

Then add the `url-pattern` to the server root URL:

[image: URL to open]

Comment: Like i told Dave, for some reason the resource is unavailable.

Comment: Provide your project reproducing the problem. Did you configure the artifact to include module compiler output?

Comment: Here's a slideshow with pics of the project: http://slideful.com/v20120206_0542406566085542_pf.htm

Comment: It doesn't show the Deployment tab settings. Also, using the default package for classes is a bad practice, consider moving your servlet in some sub-package. Check Tomcat log for possible exceptions. Can you open any static pages deployed with the same application? Does it get deployed under root context? It would be much easier if you just zip and share your project via Dropbox.

Comment: Your project has wrong URL specified (`/web.ServletSimplu`), I had to change it to `http://localhost:8080/ServletSimplu` to run on my Tomcat. My Tomcat is using port 8080. Did you change yours to use port 80? After changing port and URL the project works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Set it to your servlet mapping.

IMO opening new browser window every time you start the server is a PITA.

Comment: Tried this already, it says the requested resource is unavailable.

Comment: @Vlad Then you have an error somewhere in your configuration or code.

Comment: It looks like web.xml isn't processed.