# Creating Servlets in IntelliJ IDEA 12 Ulimate

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, intellij-idea, tomcat7

Can anybody explain to me how to create simple web project using IDEA 12 Ultimate, Tomcat 7 and servlet API, please?
I couldn't find any tutorials for this :(

Thank you.

Comment: It's like creating it any other way, except that you can set up a server (e.g., Tomcat) to run it from within the IDE.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out these  resources:

- [IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.0 Web Help:
  Servlets](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/servlets.html)
- [How to configure a server in the IntelliJ IDE (lots of
  pictures)](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Application+Servers)
- [Getting Started with Java EE 7 and GlassFish 4.0 (lots of pictures)](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Getting+Started+with+Java+EE+7+and+GlassFish+4.0)
- [IntelliJ Idea: Deploy a simple Java servlet (no JSP) to Tomcat 7
  (question on Stack
  Oveflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151460/intellij-idea-deploy-a-simple-java-servlet-no-jsp-to-tomcat-7)

Also [IntelliJ IDEA wiki](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Main_Page) page has a lot of examples and tutorials with pictures.

---

P.S.

As I see you are from Belarus, so chances are you understand Russian. Here is a **video tutorial** in Russian:

[Видеоурок IntelliJ IDEA Tomcat JSP Servlets](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0y-6On2qeg)